# how to migrate to next version....es.indices.get_alias('index_name') depreciated

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have been using the following which is now depreciated:

```
 es.indices.update_aliases({
    "actions": [
         { "add":    { "index": 'job_name', "alias": x,"filter":{"regexp":{"path.virtual":"/"+x+".*"}}}}
         ]
     })
```

I replaced with what I thought was the correct updated syntax:

```
es.indices.update_aliases(index='job_name',name=x,body={"filter":{"regexp":{"path.virtual":"/"+x+".*"}}})
```

and get the following:

File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/venv-virt1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 347, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
TypeError: update_aliases() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: what library and what version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8
elasticsearch python module/library 8.6.2

Comment: from the API docs, doesn't seem deprecated to me, but very much the same of what you were using originally: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.6.2/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.update_aliases am I reading it wrong?

Comment: The warnings had reference to this page https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1698 which although doesn't discuss update_aliases directly seems to indicate the parameters are no longer passed in a JSON format but instead directly by keyword...at least that's how I interpreted it.

Comment: weird you got a deprecation warning, the `update_aliases` api is not in the list reported in that github issue.. guess it's safe for you to ignore it